# How to get a token from a ElasticSearch server?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to connect kibana to an elasticsearch server, where the username is "elastic", which means I cannot use the user and password to connect to the server, I have to use a token.

I tried to run command `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer dGhpcyBpcyBub3Qx5...F0YS4gZG8gbm90IHRyeSB0byByZWFkIHRva2VuIQ==" http://localhost:9200`

However, this doesn't work, the error message says I did not provide enough credentials, which makes sense since this server is password protected.

And then I tried to run the command `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer dGhpcyBpcyBub3Qx5...F0YS4gZG8gbm90IHRyeSB0byByZWFkIHRva2VuIQ==" http://localhost:9200 -u elastic:password`, but it still doesn't work and tells me the command syntax is wrong.

What should I do?

Comment: which ES version you are using ?

Comment: 8.1, the latest one

Comment: did you run the `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive` to setup password ?

Comment: the password is provided by the company, so do I still have to run that?

Comment: if the password is already provide then i think so you not need to provide `Authorization: Bearer ` toekn and just use `curl -u elastic:password http://localhost:9200`